# Approximate a given number by factorials

Tags: nt.number-theory

For a pair of integers $a$ and $b$, can we approximate a given number by $\log_{a^{!^n}}b^{!^m}$ where $a^{!^n}$ is iterated factorial operator? Are there theorems to deal with this kind of questions?